# Having trouble when trying to separate multiple results with a comma

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch data from a table, and when I need to print the result then I am using comma separator to split the result. But I don't want to show the last comma.

Please see the code below:

```
 <?php if($result_sender2): 
      foreach($result_sender2 as $row_sender2): 
               echo $row_sender2->fname.','; 
      endforeach; 
      endif; 
 ?>
```

and the result is

```
Kunal,James,
```

here in the above example, I am using a comma separator. It works fine for me, but I don't want to show the last comma after "James".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use trim function

```
<?php 
$list = "";
if($result_sender2): 
      foreach($result_sender2 as $row_sender2): 
               $list = $list . $row_sender2->fname.','; 
      endforeach; 
      endif; 
$list = trim($list, ",");
echo $list

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all values you need in one array and perform implode() funciton on it - http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's the last object in the array:

```
<?php 
    if($result_sender2):
        $arrayLength = count($result_sender2); 
        foreach($result_sender2 as $row_sender2): 
            if(array_search($row_sender2,$result_sender2)+1 !== $arrayLength):
                echo $row_sender2->fname.','; 
            endif;
        endforeach; 
    endif; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
 if($result_sender2):
  $cnt = sizeof($result_sender2); 
  $i=0;
  $str = "";
  foreach($result_sender2 as $row_sender2): 
    $str .= $row_sender2->fname;
    if($i<$cnt)
    {
       $str .= ",";
    }
    $i++;

 endforeach; echo $str; endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($result_sender2): 
  $count = 0;
  foreach($result_sender2 as $row_sender2): 
           echo $row_sender2->fname;
           if ($count < count($result_sender2)) {
               echo ',';
           }
           $count++;
  endforeach; 
  endif;
```

?>